# Does "fork" always mean parallel in java?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, terminology

I am new to java world. Some names sound very funny for me.

One of them is fork... I guess it takes the fork for food to mean parallel.

Is it always the case?

For example: If I see a function called `pid forkAndExec(String... commands)` can I  assume it will always run in parallel.

Thanks

Comment: fork - means split into two or more execution streams. whenether they are physical executed in parallel depends on the hardware. You could find this out yourself by searching.

Comment: it's a fork in the road, not an eating fork.

Comment: @edthethird: and where do you think the usage of 'fork in the road' derives from ?

Answer (score 4):

To "fork" a process usually means you'll create a new carbon-copy of the current process. Some time, the term is abused to mean creating a new different child process. So far so good.

However, the "parallel" assumption is not guaranteed. It's actually not dependent on Java, but on the platform it runs on, meaning both the hardware and OS layers.

You can safely assume (wellI i would) that a forking function would indeed create a new process. However:

- how that process is actually **created** in the background is **up to the JVM's implementation**;
- how that process is **managed** and **run** is **up to the operating system** (or, more exactly, to the **kernel's scheduler**);
- whether the scheduler **can actually implement concurrency** is **up to the hardware** specs.

The scheduler may:

- decide to play nice and give you real parallelization across multiple cores or real processors,
- or it may give you an illusion of concurrency using time slices,
- or it could be mean to you and decide that your processes will be queued, just because it doesn't like you (that last scenario is unlikely, or you got yourself a fairly mean kernel, and you should file for divorce).

Also, your programs need to be implemented in such a way as to not prevent the parallelization you speak of (for instance, if the parent process is set to wait indefinitely for the child process to execute, that hardly means they run concurrently... one is merely waiting for the other one to catch up).

Also, you mention forkAndExec. Be careful, as it's easy to confuse these as well. Some functions in many languages will fork a new process and replace the existing one with it, while others will create two processes and attempt to run them in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are new to the programming world. Many idioms there borrow from the English language for things that mean something completely else. While these are often metaphors, like with fork, normally it is not possible to deduce the meaning in the programming world from the meaning outside of it. If you look for it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork), you would have to go to the [disambiguation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28disambiguation%29) and look under the computing context. There you would find the [method of creating processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29).